# How to get Physical device IDs of RFID readers using WMI?

Tags: c#, serial-port, rfid

Reading RFID's Physical Device Object Name through Serial Port using WMI in C#

I'm setting up a C# code to read signals from different RFID readers. So, I want to get Physical Device ID to recognize which device is sending which signal. So I'm trying to read device information through WMI which has more than 13xx classes.

**code**.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher objSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity");
ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = objSearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in objCollection)
{
    string info = "HardwareID : "+obj["HardwareID"];
}
```

I expected the information of each RFID reader unique physical ID.

Comment: which device information do you get? your code does give you the `HardwareID`
 `Win32_PnPEntity` represents the properties of a Plug and Play devices

Comment: It's saying WMI data: Not Found . I'm not getting it. i think i should try to use another class. But it's more than 1000 class , which one to try?

Comment: But when I try using                        "Select * From Win32_PnPSignedDriver", string info = "DeviceID : " + obj["DeviceID"]+"\nHardware"+obj["HardWareID"];                      So, i get device ID as Fax which I don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

HardwareID is a `string[]` and not a `string` so to obtain is you have to do something like this

```
var objSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity");
var objCollection = objSearcher.Get();

foreach (var queryObj in objSearcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name {0}" , queryObj["Name"]);
    if (queryObj["HardwareID"] == null)
         Console.WriteLine("HardwareID: {0}", queryObj["HardwareID"]);
    else
    {
         var arrHardwareID = (String[])(queryObj["HardwareID"]);                    
         foreach (var arrValue in arrHardwareID)
         {
             Console.Write("HardwareID: {0}\t", arrValue);
         }
    }
}
```

Also, you can always use any NuGet package to ease your work like [Kexla](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ofir.Kexla) or [ORMi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ORMi/)